# JS Geolocation did not provide a good position

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Uhh so I implemented code a while back that used geolocation and it worked then but now it throws a `GeolocationPositionError` that the message is
`Network location provider at 'https://inference.location.live.net/' : Did not provide a good position fix.` with error code `2`.

This is a snippet of the code (yes, the code runs after user input):

```js
let latLong = [0, 0];
latLong = await new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
    await navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (ret) => {
        res([ret.coords.latitude, ret.coords.longitude]);
    },
    (err) => {
        rej(err);
    });
});
console.log('latlng', latLong);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem occurs in Windows I had the same issue and solved it by updating the device's location privacy settings, allowing the apps to access to your location